# Password management like Lastpass for API interfacing

Tags: python, powershell, password-protection, lastpass

I have coded a few modules in both PowerShell and python, each accessing different APIs which requiring authentication.

I currently have it so that the usernames and passwords are typed IN the code. I know I have the option of making it prompt every time to ask for credentials or store the credentials in a static repo and static encryption which I can pull from the file. But those are not solutions to my need.

What I want to ask is, is there like a Lastpass type solution for developing APIs?

I have tried looking it up on Lastpass site itself, but I don't see anything, at least that I could understand, that would fulfill this purpose (especially for PowerShell and Python).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LastPass seems to only allow API integration for Enterprise accounts. Keepass is an alternative that is local and scriptable.

http://keepass.info/help/v2_dev/scr_sc_index.html

Comment: So Lastpass Enterprise ACTUALLY allows me to have dynamic password management for my code and APIs. I couldnt figure it out with their vagueish website description and lack of access to documentation to non-enterprise members. Looks like ill be getting it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/).

It advertises itself as "encryption as a service", is open source and has got a batteries-included REST API which you can interact with from any programming language.